# Switching the data, using the same Controller AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I was wondering how to change the data, but keep the same controller in my angular app. Basically I will have a list of activities (restaurants, parks etc...) when I click on one of these activities, The view will display all the restaurant, and same thing for the parks. I know how to do that, but I would need to create a park_ctrl and a restaurant_ctrl, and since the data will be formatted the exact same way. I just wanted to know if I could use only one controller and just change the data that it receives when I click on those buttons.

I hope my question makes sense.

Comment: Yes, you can. Just try doing it, and come back here if you have a concrete problem.

Answer (score 0):

logic around retrieving data should be the responsibility of services, so I guess you'd just call a different service in the different cases, from the same controller

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not a really good idea, but opinion based.

You can make a function :

```
function($scope){

  $scope.changePage = function (type) {
    if(type==="park"){
      $scope.parks = asynLoadFunctionToGetParks();
    }else{
      if(type === "restaurants"){
        /* same as below */
      }
    }
  };

}
```

And changing the type in your view with :

```
<button ng-click="changePage('parks')">Parks</button>
<button ng-click="changePage('restaurants')">Restaurants</button>

<div ng-if="type==='park'">
  {{parks}}
</div>


<div ng-if="type==='restaurants'">
  {{restaurants}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that most of the Angular examples available are of the "hello world" variety and so they show retrieving data directly from the Controller. The problem is that AngularJS out of the box doesn't really have a business logic layer itself, and I think most people who have added such a layer are too busy to be putting up examples.

The way I'd do this is to create a "master" service that can get all of the different data types either up front in the Run block or lazily as the user navigates the app, depending on your needs. Then I'd supply a reference to the applicable sub-collection in the route resolution (resolve property) or the isolate scope in the case of a directive.

Alternatively, the controller can ask for the data by calling `masterService.getCollection($scope.collectionName)` or something like that, but if you do that you run into the issue that `masterService` may not yet have that particular collection yet and then you have to clutter up your controller with all the promise resolution stuff as if it were a Controller's responsibility to handle that.

You could avoid that by binding to `masterService.collections[$scope.collectionName]` in the View, which would leave the Controller only exposing the collection on the $scope or controllerAs variable and the masterService still responsible for retrieving the data and making it available.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Just use different service and a common variable in the scope.

```
if (something) {
    $scope.data = restaurantsService.get();
} else {
    $scope.data = parksService.get();
}
```